# pyqt4 crashing after running the script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

```
class Render(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
  def __init__(self, urls,app, cb):



    QWebPage.__init__(self)

    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)

    self.urls = urls

    self.cb = cb

    self.app=app

    self.crawl()

    self.app.exec_()
    print(1)




  def crawl(self):
    if self.urls:

      url = self.urls.pop(0)

      print ('Downloading', url)

      self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))

    else:
      self.app.quit()
      print(2)



  def _loadFinished(self, result):
    frame = self.mainFrame()

    url = str(frame.url().toString())

    html = frame.toHtml()

    self.cb(url, html)

    self.crawl()
    class King(Resource):


                global app
                app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
                if app is None:
                    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Why it crashes after running for the second time?

Comment: What is the traceback?

Comment: QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::onlineStateChanged(bool)

Comment: Please add this to your question with proper formatting

Comment: My question is how should i load the previous instance of QApplication

Comment: It seems like you are trying to only have one instance of the program running at the same time? `.instance()` doesn't work like that

Comment: for full code refer [link](https://github.com/manthankool/test-repository/blob/master/app.py)